# PHP FILTER_SANITIZE_URL swedish domain name

Tags: php, sanitize, filter-var, filter-input

I am experimenting with `filter_input` and `filter_var` and I am currently trying to sanitize URLs with `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`.

The test program gets input from a GET variable which consists of a URL, (ex. `foo.com/bar.php?a=http://www.domain.se`). It works fine as long as I don't use swedish domain names. Ex: (`foo.com/bar.php?a=http://www.äta.se`) gets sanitized to where a = `http://www.ta.se` which obviously isn't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domains with special characters are technically not transferred with non-ASCII characters (like the ä in your case), they are punycode encoded. The calling program should encode it's URLs accordingly.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Example:
[http://www.äta.se](http://www.%C3%A4ta.se) is http://www.xn--ta-uia.se